# the json is override when i use fs.writefilesync

Tags: javascript, node.js

i wanted to add something to my son file but when I try to  add it just override my son file can someone help me with this

```
const fs = require('fs')
const chalk = require('chalk')

const getNotes = function(){
    return 'Your notes....'
}
// add note function 
const addNote = function (title, body) {
    const notes = loadNotes()
    const duplicateNotes = notes.filter(function (note) {
        return note.title === title
    })

    if (duplicateNotes.length === 0) {
        notes.push({
            title: title,
            body: body
        })
        saveNotes(notes)
        console.log(chalk.green.inverse('New note added!'))
    } else {
        console.log(chalk.red.inverse('Note title taken!'))
    }
}
const saveNotes = function(notes){
    const dataJSON = JSON.stringify(notes)
    fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', dataJSON)
}

const loadNotes = function(){
    try{
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(notes.json)
        const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString();
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
    }catch (e){
        return []
    }
} 



module.exports = {
    getNotes: getNotes,
    addNote: addNote,
}
```

when I run node app.js add --title="list" --body="apple" and then i add another different title and body it just override the --title="list" --body="apple why is that happening ?

Comment: looks like you're reading has error, so it returns the catch block ([]). check that once

Answer (score 0):

It seems you just forgot the quotes:

```js
const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync(notes.json)
```

should be

```js
const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
```